# How to stop my javascript countdown?

Tags: javascript

How can I stop my javascript function when countdown = 0?

JS:

```
var settimmer = 0;
$(function(){
  window.setInterval(function() {
      var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
      var updateTime = eval(timeCounter)- eval(1);
      $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);
    }, 1000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<b id="show-time">20</b>
```

Answer (score 4):

For one thing **remove** those `eval`s. They don't do anything.

Then all you have to do is clear the timer when it reaches zero.

```
$(function(){
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            var timeCounter = parseInt($("b[id=show-time]").text());
            $("b[id=show-time]").text(--timeCounter); // remove one
            if(!timeCounter) clearInterval(timer);
        }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easy! When you call `setInterval` it return an ID, so you can destroy the interval later. To destroy it you must use `clearInterval(id)`, and voilà!

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

```
// Activate timer
var iv = window.setInterval(...);

// Deactive timer
window.clearInterval(iv);
```

Also you should use parseInt() instead of eval():

```
$(function() {
    // Read the start value once and store it in a variable
    var timeCounter = parseInt( $("b[id=show-time]").text() );

    // Active the counter
    var iv = window.setInterval(function() {
        // Decrement by one and write back into the document
        $("b[id=show-time]").text(--timeCounter);

        // Check if counter == 0 -> stop counting
        if (0 == timeCounter) {
            window.clearInterval(iv);
            // ...do whatever else needs to be done when counter == 0 ..
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Referring to window explicitly is not necessary unless for some crazy reason `setInterval` and `clearInterval` are being shadowed in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
var i = 0,
    pid = setInterval(function() {
        if (++i > 10)
            clearInterval(pid);
    }, 1000);
```

Based on what you wanted for your code ...

```
$(function() {
    var el  = document.getElementById('show-time'),
        pid = setInterval(function() {
            // (s - i) coerces s to Number
            var t = el.innerHTML - 1;
            el.innerHTML = t;
            if (t < 1)
                clearInterval(pid);
        }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Why merge jQuery with fancy javascript? :-P

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that JS won't be 100% accurate with its timing.

Pasted code below or see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raHrm/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

var settimmer = 0,
    timeCounter = $("#show-time").html(),
    updateTime = timeCounter;

(function countDown() {
    timeCounter = $("#show-time").html();
    updateTime = parseInt(timeCounter)-1;
    $("#show-time").html(updateTime);
    if ( updateTime ) {
        setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    }
})();

});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the timer to a variable, then use `clearInterval` in-order to stop the loop. As for catching the end, use a simple conditional:

```
$(function(){
    var elem=$('strong[id="show-time"]'),settimmer=0,updateTime,t;
    t=window.setInterval(function() {
        updateTime=parseFloat(elem.html(),10)-1;
        if(updateTime==0) {
            window.clearInterval(t);
            elem.html('Done!');
        } else {
            elem.html(updateTime);
        }
    },1000);
});
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<strong id="show-time">20</strong>
```

The `<b>` tag is depreciated, try to avoid using it. Also, there is no reason to `eval()` the HTML you are getting from the element; a simple `parseFloat()` works just fine.